# Require en nodejs instancia una nueva clase

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito llamar a un método de una clase la cual no debe volver a instanciarse, ya que provoca un error.

En main.js:

```
var telegram = require('./telegram.js');
telegram.hello();
```

En telegram.js

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

function hello(req) {
        console.log("hello!!");
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

El error es por instanciar dos veces el bot de telegram:

```
Conflict: terminated by other long poll or webhook
```

Comment: Creo que los modulos en nodejs son singleton, es decir, hacerle un require a un mismo modulo dos veces te devuelve el mismo objeto, que seria lo que quieres hacer, extranno que te de ese error

Comment: Parece que no es exactamente un singleton :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas facil que veo es crear una variable global para cachear tu TelegramBot en tu `telegram.js`

```
let bot = null;
if (global.cachedModule) {
    bot = global.cachedModule;
} else {
    bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
    global.cachedModule = bot;
}

function hello(req) {
        console.log("hello!!");
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver, lo que pones de ejemplo

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

function hello(req) {
        console.log("hello!!");
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

Te exporta la función hello y sin embargo, bot no se está usando.

Si quieres crear una instancia de TelegramBot, agregarle métodos y exportar esa instancia, entonces:

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.algo = function(){}

module.exports = bot;
```

Tienes que exportar al objeto, no al método del objeto.